# Cannot import module from linux-ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, module, root

I installed the keyboard module for python with pip3 and after I runned my code the terminal shows me this message: **"ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux."** Can anybody help me how to run it well? I tried to run it by switching to "su -" and tried it on this place as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please post your script?

If you are just starting the program without a shebang it probably should not run and probably throw an `ImportError`

Try adding a shebang (*#!*) at the first line of you script.

A shebang is used in unix to select the interpreter you want to run your script.

Write this in the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

If this doesn't help try running it from the terminal using a precending dot like this:

`python3 ./{file's_name}.py`

Comment: import keyboard 
  
# It writes the content to output 
keyboard.write("GEEKS FOR GEEKS\n") 
  
# It writes the keys r, k and endofline  
keyboard.press_and_release('shift + r, shift + k, \n') 
keyboard.press_and_release('R, K') 
  
# it blocks until ctrl is pressed 
keyboard.wait('Ctrl')

Comment: Add a shebang at the begging of your script

Comment: Why wont it work?

Just add a comment and an exclamation mark and the path of the interpreter

**#!usr/bin/env python3**

Comment: OK, now I get it. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked, feel free to mark the question answered :)